# REGEXP_INSTR и символ ^ (caret)?

Tags: sql, регулярные-выражения, plsql

Как с помощью REGEXP_INSTR найти слово из набора [a-zA-Z], перед и после которого стоят знаки ^ (caret)?

`REGEXP_INSTR('jhskjdk^klsdfn^nlkn320', '\^[a-zA-Z]\^')` - возвращает ноль. Где ошибка в pattern?

Comment: В отсутствии квантификатора проблема `\^[a-zA-Z]+\^`  иначе он будет искать `^`один символ`^`. В `REGEXP_INSTR` возможно не сработает квантификатор `+` если это так используйте `{1,}` который является аналогом

Answer (score 0):

В регулярке первый символ `^` говорит о том что строка должна начинаться с [a-zA-Z], последний `$` говорит о том что строка должна заканчиваться на [a-zA-Z].

`'\\^[a-zA-Z]+\^'`